# Unauthorized Access when cURL PHP request with cookies

Tags: php, curl, cookies, authentication

I am trying to access a page, say `http://www.domain.com/profile`.  The action and login urls are the same, and I am trying to save cookies to `http://www.example.com/cookies.txt` for authentication.  Here is the code I'm using:

```
$loginURL = 'http://www.domain.com/login';
$COOKIE_FILE = 'http://wwww.example.com/cookies.txt';
$postValues = array(
    'username' => 'myusername',
    'password' => 'mypassword'
);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $loginURL); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postValues));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $COOKIE_FILE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Chrome/35.0.2309.372');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $loginURL); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_exec($curl);
if(curl_errno($curl)){throw new Exception(curl_error($curl));}

// now we are logged in, attempt to access a password-protected page
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.domain.com/profile');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $COOKIE_FILE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, USER_AGENT);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
echo curl_exec($curl);
```

It seems like the curl requests are successful, but I am getting echoed a page from the server saying "Unauthorized Access". I don't think my cookies system is working correctly? How can I check that? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE to same path as CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR. curl reads from file and writes to jar.

ETA: One likely reason your script doesn't work is that you don't send the cookie data from the first request in the second request.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work.  I should be able to see my $COOKIE_FILE contents with `echo file_get_contents($COOKIE_FILE)` but it's blank.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by not sending the cookie data?  How would I do that?

Comment: I just tried to rephrase the first sentence. You need cookie file to read from the file. But I don't know why you can't create the file. Maybe try with a local file first? Or use CURLOPT_VERBOSE, in combination with CURLOPT_STDERR.

Answer (score 0):

So the actual answer was that the login was through CAS, which necessitates a much more complicated authentication process. However, my code above was improperly using `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`, so after I made those fixes I discovered I needed a rework of the approach.